# Continue async task once started even if user navigates to another screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I want to continue async task in background once started form one screen no matter if user navigates to another screen.

From Image List screen user can select multiple images and image uploading will start. Functions for uploading images is as below.

```
dynamic _onUploadAllAssets(String albumId, AlbumManager albumManager,
      List<Asset> imageList, context, albumBloc) async {
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
      await uploadAsset(
          imageList.first, albumId, albumManager, 0, context, albumBloc);
      albumBloc.fetchAllImages(albumId);
      imageList.remove(imageList.first);
      albumBloc.getSelectedImage(imageList);
    }
  }

dynamic uploadAsset(Asset asset, String albumId, AlbumManager albumManager,
      int index, context, albumBloc) async {
    final String uuid = Uuid().v1();
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2;

    final width = asset.originalWidth * height / asset.originalHeight;

    final imageByte = await asset.getByteData(quality: 100);

    final base64Image = base64Encode(imageByte.buffer.asUint8List());
    await uploadAlbumImage(albumId, base64Image, uuid, false, index, albumBloc);
    final compressedImageBytes = await asset.getThumbByteData(
      width.round(),
      height.round(),
    );
    final compressedImageU8 = compressedImageBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
    final compressedBase64 = base64Encode(compressedImageU8);
    await uploadAlbumImage(
        albumId, compressedBase64, uuid, true, index, albumBloc);
  }

Future<bool> uploadAlbumImage(String albumId, String base64Image, String uuid,
      bool isThumbnail, int index, albumBloc) async {
    await albumManager.connectFirebase();
    final Directory systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;

    if (albumManager.circleAlbumCacheDir == null) {
      await albumManager.getCacheDirectory(albumId);
    }

    final encryptor = encryption.StringEncryption();
    final encryptedImage = await encryptor.getEncryption(base64Image);

    final String prefix = isThumbnail ? 'thumbnail_' : 'img_';

    final File file = File('${systemTempDir.path}/tmp$prefix$uuid.txt');
    if (file.existsSync()) {
      await file.delete();
    }
    await file.create();

    await file.writeAsString(encryptedImage);

    final StorageReference preRef =
        albumManager.storageReference.child(albumId);

    final StorageReference thumbnailRef =
        preRef.child('thumbnail').child('thumbnail_$uuid.txt');

    final StorageReference imageRef =
        preRef.child('images').child('img_$uuid.txt');

    final StorageReference ref = isThumbnail ? thumbnailRef : imageRef;

    final StorageUploadTask task = ref.putFile(
      file,
      StorageMetadata(
        contentLanguage: 'en',
        customMetadata: <String, String>{'activity': 'uploadEventImage'},
      ),
    );
    task.events.listen((storageTaskEvent) {
      final _progess = storageTaskEvent.snapshot.bytesTransferred.toDouble() /
          storageTaskEvent.snapshot.totalByteCount.toDouble();
      albumBloc.syncFileUploading(uuid, isThumbnail, _progess, index);
    });
    await task.onComplete;

    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
      ref.delete();
      await file.delete();
    } else if (isThumbnail) {
      final String thumbnailUrl = await thumbnailRef.getDownloadURL();
      final String imageUrl = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
      await albumManager.addImageToFolder(
          albumId, uuid, thumbnailUrl, imageUrl, true);
      await albumManager.getCacheDirectory(albumId);
      albumManager.cacheImage(
          base64Image, '${albumManager.circleAlbumCacheDir}/thumb_$uuid.png');
    } else {
      await albumManager.getCacheDirectory(albumId);
      albumManager.cacheImage(
          base64Image, '${albumManager.circleAlbumCacheDir}/img_$uuid.png');
    }

    await file.delete();
    return task.isSuccessful;
  }
```

Issue is once image uploading is started and user navigates to another screen then the image which is uploading will be completed but it is not uploading remaining images.

For loop stop executing when user navigates to another screen or back to previous screen. I want to continue executing for loop until all images are uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Embedding _onUploadAllAssets inside another asynchronous function should do the job no? (without using the await keyword...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run in the background while not displaying to the user any clue on the progress then you have to use 'isolates'. But if you want to show the user about the progress of the task, then create a widget containing the progressBar as a widget, and in every page use it as a child widget.